# ASP.NET Core Page doesn't reload page on back button

Tags: asp.net-core, page-refresh

I'm a newbie to ASP.NET and web development.  I'm having some issues with a page that doesn't want to reload when I click the browser's back button or use `<a href='javascript:history.go(-1)'>Go Back to List</a>`.  I'm getting the following error:

*Resubmit the form?To display this webpage correctly, resubmit the data you entered earlier. By doing this, you will repeat any action this page previously performed.
Refresh to resubmit the data needed to load this page.
ERR_CACHE_MISS*

The page is an Index Page (e.g. https://localhost:5001/Contact/Index) which loads a Datagrid containing contacts. I have a link for each contact to display details about the contact they select represented by the following code snippet:

```
<a asp-controller="Contact" asp-action="View" asp-route-id="@contact.Id">
     <i class="fas fa-info-circle"></i>
</a>
```

The controller for the page is as follows:

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Index()
{
 ContactIndexViewModel contactIndexViewModel = new ContactIndexViewModel();
 var contacts = from c in _contactRepository.AllCompanyContacts(0) select c;
 contactIndexViewModel.FilterExpression = "Select a Filter ...";
 contactIndexViewModel.Filter = "A";
 contactIndexViewModel.Contacts = contacts;
 return View(contactIndexViewModel);
}

[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Index(ContactIndexViewModel contactIndexViewModel)
{
   var contacts = from c in _contactRepository.AllActiveContacts select c;
   string filter = contactIndexViewModel.Filter;
   contacts = contacts.Where(c => c.FirstName.ToUpper().StartsWith(filter))
                      .OrderBy(c => c.FirstName);
   contactIndexViewModel.Contacts = contacts;
   return View(contactIndexViewModel);
}
```

The details page loads fine, however when I click the back button to return to the list from the details page, I get the error I described above. Refreshing the page reloads it just fine. Am I doing something I shouldn't or not doing something I should be doing? The URL has the correct address which is:  *https://localhost:5001/Contact/Index*

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks a bunch.

--- Val

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a demo can produce `ERR_CACHE_MISS`,and in the demo the cause is the form in `index.cshtml` doesn't have`method="get"`.When I click "Details" after I submit the form,I will get Error.

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Index(string movieGenre, string searchString)
        {
            // Use LINQ to get list of genres.
            IQueryable<string> genreQuery = from m in _context.Movie
                                            orderby m.Genre
                                            select m.Genre;

            var movies = from m in _context.Movie
                         select m;

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
            {
                movies = movies.Where(s => s.Title.Contains(searchString));
            }

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(movieGenre))
            {
                movies = movies.Where(x => x.Genre == movieGenre);
            }

            var movieGenreVM = new MovieGenreViewModel
            {
                Genres = new SelectList(await genreQuery.Distinct().ToListAsync()),
                Movies = await movies.ToListAsync()
            };

            return View(movieGenreVM);
        }
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
        {
            IQueryable<string> genreQuery = from m in _context.Movie
                                            orderby m.Genre
                                            select m.Genre;

            var movies = from m in _context.Movie
                         select m;

            var movieGenreVM = new MovieGenreViewModel
            {
                Genres = new SelectList(await genreQuery.Distinct().ToListAsync()),
                Movies = await movies.ToListAsync()
            };

            return View(movieGenreVM);
        }
```

Index.cshtml:

```
   <p>
    <a asp-action="Create">Create New</a>
</p>

<form asp-controller="Movies" asp-action="Index">
    <p>
        <select asp-for="MovieGenre" asp-items="Model.Genres">
            <option value="">All</option>
        </select>

        Title: <input asp-for="SearchString">
        <input type="submit" value="Filter" />
    </p>
</form>

<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Movies[0].Title)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Movies[0].ReleaseDate)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Movies[0].Genre)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Movies[0].Price)
            </th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model.Movies)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Title)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ReleaseDate)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Genre)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Price)
                </td>
                <td>
                    <a asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="@item.Id">Edit</a> |
                    <a asp-action="Details" asp-route-id="@item.Id">Details</a> |
                    <a asp-action="Delete" asp-route-id="@item.Id">Delete</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Detail.cshtml:

```
<div>
    <h4>Movie</h4>
    <hr />
    <dl class="row">
        <dt class = "col-sm-2">
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Title)
        </dt>
        <dd class = "col-sm-10">
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Title)
        </dd>
        <dt class = "col-sm-2">
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ReleaseDate)
        </dt>
        <dd class = "col-sm-10">
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.ReleaseDate)
        </dd>
        <dt class = "col-sm-2">
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Genre)
        </dt>
        <dd class = "col-sm-10">
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Genre)
        </dd>
        <dt class = "col-sm-2">
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Price)
        </dt>
        <dd class = "col-sm-10">
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Price)
        </dd>
    </dl>
</div>
<div>
    <a asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="@Model.Id">Edit</a> |
    <a asp-action="Index">Back to List</a> |
    <a href='javascript:history.go(-1)'>history.go</a>
</div>
```

Result:
[image]

The first solution is to change the form type to get,the second is to use `<a asp-action="Index">Back to List</a>` rather than `javascript:history.go(-1)`.

Result:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the post.  Unfortunately, this isn't working for me.  By placing a <form="get"> line, the controller only fires the [HttpGet] method.

Comment: Yiyi, even though it didn't exactly work as you had it laid out, the recommendations that you made actually got me on the right track and it resolved my issue.  In the end, I ended up making a single Index method in the controller with the (string? filter, ?bool byFirstName) as parameters.  Thanks again.